# How can I ignore all java.io exception?

Tags: python, jython

I use these code in my jython script

```
    try:
        my_func()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        pass
```

But I still get exception such as

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./filename (No such file or directory)
```

or

```
java.io.EOFException: java.io.EOFException
```

How can I catch all these java exceptions in jython?

Env info:

jython version 2.7.1

java runtime 10.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java exceptions in Jython are not derived from Python's `Exception` class. To catch them separately from Python exceptions import `java.lang.Exception` with some local name not overlapping with standard Exception and add another `except` clause:

```
from java.lang import Exception as JException

try:
    my_func()
except Exception as e:
    print "python ex", e
except JException as ex:
    print "java ex", ex
```

Comment: Please explain why this solution work, answers with only code may be deleted.

Comment: this only works with python 2 because of the old print syntax, and old exception syntax. Consider upgrading to new syntax (which also works with python 2.7). OP has used `except Exception as e`. There's potential in your answer, but add some explanation and make it python 3 compliant.

Comment: @jcubic okay, added an explanation.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre as you may know the latest Jython version is 2.7.1; considering the project activity Jython 3.5 will never be released.